# How to use "pickpocket" as verb

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to use the verb *pickpocket* before the item being taken from someone's pocket?

> Pickpocket a pouch of gold

Or can you only use *pickpocket* before the person whose item is being taken?

> Pickpocket a tourist

Comment: Dictionary example would have been enough.

Comment: @Chaos: Now that you made me think of it, this might be a GenRef...

Comment: @Alenanno Least you answered it.

Comment: Would it be correct to use pickpocket with the object being lifted? Ex. Pickpocket a pouch. Or can you only use pickpocket with people who have pockets? Ex. Pickpocket a tourist.

Comment: @Abdulla obviously, the word itself was coin in terms with that situation. :P

Comment: @Abdulla, I think the question about what type of object *pickpocket* takes is a good one and on-topic. Please edit your question to reflect what you said in your comment.

Comment: Actually, while "pickpocket" isn't really used as a verb much -- and almost never in the fashion that the poster is wondering about -- neither does the dictionary nor thesaurus make clear what words are most suitable for describing what a pickpocket does.

If this is a very young learner, or an EFL student, then i think the question is perfectly suitable for the site.  This is not the sort of question that common reference materials answer well.

Comment: @Kyle: The OALD provides many, many examples of words in use. I agree with the existing close votes as general reference.

Comment: Yes, i can read a dictionary as well as anyone else.  However, when i type "pickpocket" into OALD (a dictionary i recommend my students against, BTW), i get a single definition, and no verb forms.

But even when we get to other, more useful dictionaries, the question the poster is asking is specifically which verbs are most used as the active form of "pickpocket", and that answer is not easily gleaned.  Looking at the various online thesauruses i've got, here, i see about twenty or thirty different verbs, of which only a few actually answer the question posed.

Comment: Further, the poster specifically is asking if he *should* say "X pickpockets b's money."   In fact, this is a usage question, and so is **not** something easily intuited from either Google, or a dictionary.  In fact, "pickpocket", when used as a verb, is only very rarely transitive -- and then, usually by pedants and the naive.  More commonly, other verbs are used, and as i indicated above, there is no way for the poster to know which ones are apropos without asking somebody.  Answering such questions is what this site is for.

Comment: @Kyle: If you can make a valid case for why this should be reopened, we can vote to do so. However, questions can be "general reference"--by a native speaker or a foreign learner--and this means that the OP should have done a little research beforehand. We ask this of all posters, so that we can make sure to give answers which are helpful above the level of that given by a dictionary.

Comment: @KylePearson: I'm generally not a huge fan of closing such questions as Gen Ref, because a knowledgeable answer could expand on subtle differences and points of style and usage. However, as far as Gen Ref goes, the fact that both (sub)senses are clearly mentioned on Dictionary.com would seem to indicate that this answer is very easy to find: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pickpocket

Comment: I believe this question is misunderstood. It is NOT "What does pickpocket mean," (a general reference question). It is "How do you use it?" (Answer, by splitting the verb "pick" and the noun "pocket" around the object, e.g. a tourist: "Pick a tourist's pocket.")

Answer (score 3):

Typically, "pickpocket" isn't used in this way, although it can be, and is listed in dictionaries as a verb.  Usually, someone might say "I was pickpocketed" (i.e. -- an intransitive usage), but it's rather rare to hear someone say "S/He pickpocketed his/her money."

Most times that I have come across this idea, the verb used is "lift", as in:

"You lift a pouch of gold from your victim."

Other common verbs are to "steal", "pilfer", "swipe", and -- in Britain (but not in the US), to "pinch".

Comment: +1 for alternative verbs that *can* take an object other than the victim(s). *Purloin* also comes to mind, but again that might be a bit British (and/or dated).

Comment: "Purloin", though, is so much more fun to say....

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that "pickpocket" is primarily a noun, it's also a verb. The verb means **steal from the pockets of (someone)**.

The only occurrences I found are with a noun that refers to people, e.g. *tourists*, or without any argument, so a intransitive verb. The examples are these ones:

> 1. "*She stopped in New Orleans where she skillfully pickpocketed tourists.*"
> 2. [no obj.] — "*An elderly man caught pickpocketing in Times Square.*"
>      <sub>[NOAD]</sub>

I couldn't find anything where you use the "object" where you take the money from. The only one I found was "*to pick sb's pocket*".

Answer (score 2):

*Pickpocket* is primarily used as a noun, but it [can](http://www.personal.psu.edu/lbg10/blogs/liminality_rules/2008/04/stolen-wallet-in-san-francisco.html) [be](http://www.holidaywatchdog.com/43177-Barcelona-Ayre_Hotel_Gran_Via-Holiday-Review.html) [used](http://blog.travelpod.com/travel-blog-entries/jathomaz/1/1215694800/tpod.html) as a [verb](http://www.city-data.com/forum/florida/116209-have-you-ever-been-victim-crime.html). But if you are a pickpocket, you probably shouldn't go around telling anyone that you are going to pickpocket a pouch of gold from someone!

Answer (score 2):

I would say the "pickpocket" is a compound word, in which "pick" is a verb, and "pocket" is a noun (except when it is a reference to the PERSON who does the same).

In American English at least, you don't "pickpocket" a tourist. Instead, you pick a tourist's POCKET. (Split up the verb and noun around tourist.)

You don't "pickpocket" a pouch of gold. You pick a pocket (or pouch) of gold. (Pocket and pouch are synonyms in this context.)